# Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 DreamSpark Product Key

Tags: visual-studio-2013, dreamspark, product-key

My name is Thanos and I'm a student from Greece. Through DreamSpark's site I was licenced in VS Ultimate 2013 distribution. I managed to install it on my Desktop computer as well as my laptop and save the .iso file in both my computers but I didn't save the Product Key, because I knew any time wanted I could retrieve it from my order history. Now the problem is that dreamspark stoped the distribution VS Ultimate and hence they couldn't help to retrieve the key when I contact them. Is there any way to retrieve the key myself or do something so that I don't lose my credentials and my licence to the product?

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately you will not be able to retrieve the key.
Both the subscriber download of VS Ultimate 2013 and the key are removed from Dreamspark.

Why not use VS 2015?

Comment: Because I thought it's worth having the Ultimate Edition which have more features than the 2015 Community!